# Contact form 7 add textbox on radiobutton checked

Tags: wordpress, forms, radio-button, contact-form-7

I have two radio button in my form (Radio 1,  Radio 2)

When i am click on Radio 2 at that time one textbox is create in form.

I have used contact form 7

**Thanks,**

Comment: have you working URL if yes share it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can show textbox in your form on radio button checked by using `Conditional Fields for Contact Form 7` plugin.

Please follow [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/) link. It provides setting to hide or show particular field on select another field by using condition logic.

It should work for you as you needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Welcome @Sam, Hope you will find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

hi put this html into your contact form above send button

```
 <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="H" onclick="hide();"/>radio1  
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="L" onclick="show();"/>radio2
        <TEXTAREA id="area" style="display: none;" NAME="data" ROWS=10 COLS=50></TEXTAREA>
```

then put script into themes header or footer

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">
            function show() { document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'block'; }
            function hide() { document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'none'; }
          </script>
```

```js
        function show() { document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'block'; }
        function hide() { document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'none'; }
```

```html
 <form name="radios">
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="H" onclick="hide();"/>Radio 1
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="L" onclick="show();"/>Radio 2  
        <TEXTAREA id="area" style="display: none;" NAME="data" ROWS=10 COLS=50></TEXTAREA>   
      </form>
```